# How to bulk edit/replace numbers in Notepad++

Tags: replace, notepad++

I want to change the following:

```
 0.25
 10.00
 10.00
```

to

```
 "0.25"
 "10.00"
 "10.00"
```

So that means changing to: "(number)"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

- Find: `(\d+\.\d+)`
- Replace: `"$1"`
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>